# How can we count the distinct values of an entity property on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, count, distinct

I am trying to get the distinct count for a projection property on google app engine high replication datastore. 
Part of my model is like this:

```
class Hit(ndb.Model):
  accountId = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  sessionId = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
  pageId = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

So, the model stores all hits to a page from different sessions. 
What I want to have is the count of distinct sessions which has at least one of 2 specific pageIds for a given accountId.

My desired query is like this:

```
Hit.query(ndb.AND(Hit.accountId == "acct1", ndb.OR(Hit.pageId == "page1", Hit.pageId == "page2")), projection=['sessionId'], distinct=True).count()
```

But, this returns an exception:
BadRequestError: cannot specify group_by without a projection

So, I tried doing it like this:

```
len(Hit.query(ndb.AND(Hit.accountId == "acct1", ndb.OR(Hit.pageId == "page1", Hit.pageId == "page2")), projection=['sessionId'], distinct=True).fetch())
```

Unfortunately, this query counts duplicate "sessionId"s! (i.e. it does NOT return distinct values)
e.g. for the entities below:

```
accountId    sessionId     pageId
---------    ---------     ------
acct1        sess1         page1
acct1        sess1         page2
```

I am expecting to get a result of "1", but the query returns "2" although I am trying to get the count of distinct sessionIds!
I know that I can use a set() to filter the duplicate sessionIds but in that case I have to iterate over all results and this is not preferable as the number of entities is quite much. 
I've seen posts that this cannot be done on GAE. 
Well, this is very weird for me becasue if I use only one

```
Hit.pageID == "<page_id>"
```

statement in the query above, it works fine, it doesn't count duplicate sessionIds as is expected. So, I don't understand why it returns incorrect result in my case.

Any comments, ideas are welcome..

Answer (score 0):

.count() only returns the number of entities returned, and you have separate entities when the pageId are different, so everything looks like it's behaving as designed.

The best way is probably to store the count that you're interested in, and update that count as the pages are fetched, then query specifically for that count when you want it.

Otherwise, you'll need to parse through all your entities and update the count manually.

Comment: Thanks @dragonx, but unfortunately, I need all counts for all pageId pairs. If I want to store count values seperately, I'll have to store a huge amount of data (i.e. unique_pageIds x (unique_pageIds - 1) entities; given that an account has ~10,000 unique pages, that'll make ~100 million entities per account(!)) which I prefer not to.